# Loading request start-up time variation in google app engine?

Tags: google-app-engine

We have created an application using framework spring + strut2. Loading request start-up time varies from time to time. for **example** sometimes it takes 10 to 15 sec,15 to 20,sometimes  more then 30sec.

**may i know the reason and how to reduce loading request time.**

Answer (score 1):

You instance closes down when there is no traffic and it can take a while to start up again if (for example) you have lots of imports etc.

You can keep it running constantly with a cron job (not recommended, wasteful) or take a look at [warmup requests](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/adminconsole/instances#Warmup_Requests)

That might not help as the first request is sent directly to the instance in any case. So you might want to change the idle instances value:

> A high minimum allows you to prime the application for rapid spikes in request load. App Engine keeps that number of instances in reserve at all times, so an instance is always available to serve an incoming request, but you pay for those instances. This functionality replaces the deprecated "Always On" feature, which ensured that a fixed number of instances were always available for your application.

[Setting the Number of Idle Instances](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/adminconsole/performancesettings#minimum)

Of course, you will pay for that but as they never stop running you should find no delay on startup as it only startsup the once.

Comment: @Paul.. thank you for your quick response. May i know why loading request start-up time varies from time to time.

Comment: I don't think anybody knows the answer to that. Likely down to what's happening "under the covers".